# How to redirect hive query output to text file with header and column name having space

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have hive able product with rating.

```
Id,     productid, rating,       ProdBarCode    
42      96         5         881107178    
168     151       5           884288058    
110     307       4           886987260    
58      144        4           884304936    
62      21         3           879373460    
279  832        3           881375854    
237  514        4           879376641
```

I want to write a query find average product rating of product to pipe separated text file with header using  `hive -e"query" > output.txt`

OUTPUT Format:-`|Productid|average rating|`

Solution:

`hive -e " select C.value from (select 1 key, '|Productid|average rating|' value union all select 2 key , concat('|',concat_ws('|', Productid, averagerating),'|') value from (select CAST(A.productid AS STRING) AS Productid, CAST(A.averagerating AS STRING) AS averagerating from (select productid, avg(rating) averagerating from product group by productid sort by productid ) AS A where A.averagerating > 2) B sort by key) C " > output.txt`

Is this query correct? Is there any other simple way to redirect the output in text file with header and column name having spaces (average rating)?

Any suggestion